# Programmatically interrogate Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant

I wish to write a java program that will interrogate a specified Ant build.xml file, listing out EVERY detail in the build file, such as high level details like build file description (which I have managed to achieve) down to low level detail such as each and every path/pathelement location, all the property names and their values set in the entire build script etc.

I have been using code such as this:-

```
    File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
    Project p = new Project();
    p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
    p.init();
    p.initProperties();
    ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
    p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
    helper.parse(p, buildFile);
```

I am unable to get at the lowest level details, is this possible?